# Submit the form based on ajax result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page that I want to manually or pro-grammatically submit. But before the page is allowed to be submitted, a functions [create_impi_num(x)] need to kick of to store data using "$.post('" in that function .

The Problem: 
IF I set the submit(function(e) to return false the functions are called and my data is stored. IF I set the return to true, my form is posted but my functions are ignored.

Here is my Code:

```
$('#pay-and-complete').submit(function(e) {

 var ok = confirm('Do you really want to save your data?');
    if (ok) {

     var CanPay;
     var igroupid =  Number($('#hid-step3-entryid').val());

     //function here
      create_impi_num($('#hid-parc-id').val(),$('#hid-step3-entryid').val());

      return true;
   }
    else {
     //Prevent the submit event and remain on the screen
     create_impi_num($('#hid-parc-id').val(),$('#hid-step3-entryid').val());
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

  });
```

I have spend hours trying to find a solution. If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It simply can't be done the way you want.

jQuery `post` function excutes ayncrounsly meaning it will return sometime in the furture, in the meanwhile the code continue to be executed. Until the result returned the submit function is already done.

What you can do is on the `post` callback if you need to submit, use javascript native functions to submit or redirect.

Comment: AHA! Thank you Gordon for the advise! I have changed the code to create a .click(function event and then do stuff.. THEN after all checks out from my function I do a .submit(). It now works fine.

Comment: @PhilipMcLennan, I'm glad to hear, you should accept the answer with the check sign on the left of the answer if it helped you or write your own answer and accept it. [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) Good luck!